# SQL Query Averages

Tags: sql

Consider the following movie database:

[image]

I am trying to answer the following problem:

> Find the difference between the average rating of movies released before 1980 and the average rating of movies released after 1980. (Make sure to calculate the average rating for each movie, then the average of those averages for movies before 1980 and movies after. Don't just calculate the overall average rating before and after 1980.)

I wrote the following:

```
SELECT Movie.title, avg(Rating.stars), Movie.year
FROM Movie 
INNER JOIN Rating ON Movie.mID = Rating.mID
INNER JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.rID = Rating.rID    
GROUP BY Rating.mID, Movie.year
ORDER BY year
```

This gives the average rating for each movie. Would I need to write two subqueries to get the difference in the averages before and after 1980?

Comment: Your query result is average rating per movie per year (assuming your JOINs are correct).

Comment: You can use a case statement of some sort to derive before/after 1980, and group by that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is any issue using a case statement.

```
SELECT
avg(case when movie.year <= 1980 then Rating.stars else null end) as 'pre-1980 average', 
avg(case when movie.year > 1980 then Rating.stars else null end) as 'post-1980 average',
from ...
```

You can calculate the difference from there...key here is the use of null in the case statement, average does not count null towards the total number of values (null is not a 0 afterall).

Edit : you are looking for a one row response to the question right?  get rid of the movie.title and movie.year columns in your select and grouping for that.  Closer to this:

```
SELECT
avg(case when movie.year <= 1980 then Rating.stars else null) - 
avg(case when movie.year > 1980 then Rating.stars else null) as 'difference',
from ...
```